# Vaadin and spring deployment

Tags: spring, vaadin

I want to use Vaadin as UI with sprig service as backend.
Can i run the UI modules in one tomcat server and the spring services in  different servers?
The reason for this is to ensure that we have a clean separation for UI and backend as each of them may have their own spring context files and i don't want to mix them up..

I may have multiple servers for spring services and one or two servers to serve UI...Is it possible?

- kdaal

Answer (score 0):

OK so this is an old question, but still:

Yes.

In our system, we have a "back end server", which talks to the database, and a front end server which serves up a Vaadin UI.

We use our own hand-rolled proxies to invoke methods on the back end server to server data, and populate Vaadin containers.

There is absolutely no reason why you could do the same using Spring remoting.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Stuff Vaadin add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/spring-stuff) allows you to define and maintain separate Spring application contexts for the web application as a whole, and each Vaadin application instance.

Disclaimer: I'm the author